# How to bind client key for particular client class in Awesome WM?

Tags: awesome-wm

I want to bind client key to perform some operation on `Mod1-q` shortcut only in vivaldi browser, so I write in `clientkeys` config in my `rc.lua`:

```
awful.key({"Mod1"}, "q",
function (c)
  if c.class == "Vivaldi-stable" then
    someoperation()
  end
end,
{description = "Some operation only in browser", group = "client"})
```

The problem with this code is that `someoperation()` is performed if `Mod1+q` is pressed in `vivaldi` browser, but all other window got no input at all, while I want them to receive `Mod1+q` as before. Is there some obvious way to bind keys only to specific client class, maybe via `match` function?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to a suitable entry (with `class = "Vivaldi[-]stable"`) to `awful.rules`:

```
callback = function(c)
    local keys = c:keys()
    c:keys(gears.table.join(keys,
        awful.key({"Mod1"}, "q", someoperation,
        { description = "Some operation only in browser", group = "client"})))
end
```